# Match a word that doesn't contain a dot and isn't an IP regex

Tags: python, regex, dns

I want to get a list and filter it (In this case it's a list of a record, a domain name and an ip).
I want the list to be something like so:

```
10.0.0.10 ansible0 ben1.com  
ansible1 ben1.com  10.0.0.10
```

Aka you can put the ip the zone and the record anywhere and it will still catch them.

Now i got 2 regex, one that catches the domain (with the dot) and the IP:

Domain: `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}`

Simple IP: `(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}`

With these i can catch in python all the domain names and put them into a list and all ips.

Now i only need to catch the "subdomain" (In this case ansible1 and ansible0).

I want it to be able to have numbers and characters like `- _ *` and so on, anything but a `.`.

How can i do it via regex?

Comment: Does [this work for you](https://regex101.com/r/NR2P1r/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with 3 alternations and 3 named groups:

```sh
(?P<domain>[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})|
(?P<ip>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})|
(?P<sub>[^\s.]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NR2P1r/1/)

Named groups `domain` and `ip` are using regex you've provided. 3rd group is `(?P<sub>[^\s.]+)` that is matching 1+ of any characters that are not dot and not whitespace.

---

**Code:**

```py
import re

arr = ['10.0.0.10 ansible0 ben1.com', 'ansible1 ben1.com  10.0.0.10']

rx = re.compile(r'(?P<domain>[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})|(?P<ip>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})|(?P<sub>[^\s.]+)')

subs = []
for i in arr:
     for m in rx.finditer(i):
             if (m.group('sub')): subs.append(m.group('sub'))

print (subs)
```

**Output:**

```
['ansible0', 'ansible1']
```

Comment: I'd put that pattern in a non-capturing group and repeat it 3 times. Calling `match.groupdict()` will then show all the captures.

Comment: How would i add it to a python script?
I want a list for the domains, ips and sub domains.
Atm i am just using findall with the 2 regex i 've provided and that puts them into a list

Comment: Please use `re.finditer` and store each group separately in 3 separate lists